# need to create a workflow to send an email after 30 days of the receiving date

Tags: workflow

I have created a list in SharePoint and on the list I have a column for  "receiving date". I need to have a workflow to send an email 30 days after the receiving date.

Is there any way to make this work?

Note that i have already  follow the steps which was provided but it did not work with me .

Comment: Should it work on item change also (changing Receiving Date) ?

Answer (score 4):

What kind of SharePoint are you using? 2010, 2013, 2016? On premises?

One solution I know works for 2013 On prem is using the `Information Management Policy Settings` in the list library.

### First:

Make a simple workflow that just send the relative emails in SharePoint Designer. If that's all you need it to do, shouldn't need to add any conditionals:

[image: img4]

Save and publish the workflow as whatever you'd like it to be called.

### Next:

Set up the document retention policies in Library Settings...

Go to your library's Settings, then under `Permissions and Management` select `Information Management Policy Settings`. In the new page, select the relevant content type (example, `Document` or `Form`).

[image: img1]

Select `Enable Retention` then `Add a retention stage`:

[image: img2]

In the popup, select the DateTime field you want the workflow to be based on. In this example I used `Created`. Then change the duration and units to run the stage at. I set this to `30 days`. If you want the workflow to run 30 days *before* the date, enter "-30". Under action, change the drop down to `Start a workflow` and select the desired workflow. I just put the `approval` workflow down as a sample.

[image: img3]

Click OK on the popup, OK on the Edit Policy page, and it should work.

This setup should run your Email workflow 30 days after your Date column that was specified.

Comment: Thank you but it did not work